# Choosing a source for update

Tags: update-manager, software-sources

How can I choose the address http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ for ubuntu update and package download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to regenerate your `sources.list` you could use http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Select your **country**, your Ubuntu version and choose the repositories you want.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Delete all contents and then paste (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>) the output from the above mentioned site. Save and update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If something is wrong:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a **Terminal**. First make a backup:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
```

You can open `/etc/apt/sources.list` in a text editor with `root` privileges:

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then go to **Edit** - **Replace** and replace the current country ID with `ir`. For example if you have `us.archive.ubuntu.com` you would write in the **Search** box `us.archive` and in the **Replace with** `ir.archive` (not only `us`/`ir` because it may replace in-word occurences).

Save the file and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you get errors, revert to original file:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Please add this solution into your accepted answer as another option